# binary search tree missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

Trying to construct the Binary search tree here

```
class Node: 
    # Constructor to create a new node 
    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data 
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        
class BSTree():
    def __init__(self, rootdata):
        self.root = Node(rootdata)
        
    def insert(self, data, cur_node):
        if data < cur_node.data:
            if cur_node.left == None:
                cur_node.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.insert(data, cur_node.left)
                
        elif data > cur_node.data:
            if cur_node.right == None:
                cur_node.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.insert(data, cur_node.right)
        else:
            print("Duplicate value!")
         
    def find(self, data, cur_node):
        if data < cur_node.data and cur_node.left:
            return self.find(data, cur_node.left)
        elif data > cur_node.data and cur_node.right:
            return self.find(data, cur_node.right)
        if data == cur_node.data:
            return True
        return False
    def PreOder(self,root):
        if root == None:
            pass
        else:
            print(root.data)
            self.PreOrder(root.left)
            self.PreOrder(root.right)

a = BSTree()
a.insert(3)
a.insert(4)
a.insert(7)
a.insert(34)
a.insert(24)
a.insert(2)
a.insert(49)
print(a.find(3))
print(a.PreOrder(3))
```

I am getting an error message: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rootdata'

How to fix and print the binary search tree?

- Also, what I have up there is just the random number I am try to construct the binary tree out from the list I have
  mylist = [1,3,2,4,12,14,23,43,23,44,34,43]

Comment: You defined `BSTree()` to require a parameter `rootdata`.  You did not supply any such parameter when you instantiated the class.

Comment: How to allocate the parameter? New to python...

Comment: Just start off with `a = BSTree(3)` (and get rid of the first `.insert()`).

Comment: You also have to add a second parameter when calling each insert method. It should look like `a.insert(4, a.root)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working and properly formatted update of your code. Not sure what it's doing exactly, but it should give you some clues to solve your task. Maybe you could use an IDE like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/es-es/pycharm/) to help you out with python specific stuff.

```
class Node:
    # Constructor to create a new node
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BSTree:
    def __init__(self, rootdata):
        self.root = Node(rootdata)

    def insert(self, data, cur_node):
        if data < cur_node.data:
            if cur_node.left is None:
                cur_node.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.insert(data, cur_node.left)

        elif data > cur_node.data:
            if cur_node.right is None:
                cur_node.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.insert(data, cur_node.right)
        else:
            print("Duplicate value!")

    def find(self, data, cur_node):
        if data < cur_node.data and cur_node.left:
            return self.find(data, cur_node.left)
        elif data > cur_node.data and cur_node.right:
            return self.find(data, cur_node.right)
        if data == cur_node.data:
            return True
        return False

    def pre_order(self, root):
        if root is None:
            pass
        else:
            print(root.data)
            self.pre_order(root.left)
            self.pre_order(root.right)

a = BSTree(3)
a.insert(4, a.root)
a.insert(7, a.root)
a.insert(34, a.root)
a.insert(24, a.root)
a.insert(2, a.root)
a.insert(49, a.root)
print(a.find(3, a.root),)
print(a.pre_order(a.root))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- Your `BSTree` constructor does not create an *emtpy* tree, but a tree with already one node, and so it expects the data for that node as argument. This design is not good, because it does not support the concept of an *empty* tree. So the constructor should change and just set `self.root` to `None`.
- `insert` takes also more arguments than expected: it does so because it uses that argument for implementing recursion. There are many ways to make it work, but I prefer that the recursive call is made in OOP-style, i.e. the recursive `insert` method should be placed in the `Node` class, and act on `self` instead of on an extra argument. The `insert` method on the `BSTree` class can then just be a wrapper around that method, where it gets called on the root node.
- A similar issue occurs with `find`. The solution can be the same as for `insert`.
- And again, the issue occurs also with `preOrder`: it takes a node as argument. Same solution as discussed above. I would also avoid *printing* in a method. Instead *yield* the values.

So here is how that would look:

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data 
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, data):
        if data < self.data:
            if not self.left:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.insert(data)
        elif data > self.data:
            if not self.right:
                self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            print("Duplicate value!")

    def find(self, data):
        if data < self.data and self.left:
            return self.left.find(data)
        elif data > self.data and self.right:
            return self.right.find(data)
        return data == self.data

    def preOrder(self):
        yield self.data
        if self.left:
            yield from self.left.preOrder()
        if self.right:
            yield from self.right.preOrder()


class BSTree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        
    def insert(self, data):
        if not self.root:
            self.root = Node(data)
        else:
            self.root.insert(data)
         
    def find(self, data):
        return self.root.find(data) if self.root else False

    def preOrder(self):
        if self.root:
            yield from self.root.preOrder()


a = BSTree()
a.insert(3)
a.insert(4)
a.insert(7)
a.insert(34)
a.insert(24)
a.insert(2)
a.insert(49)
print(a.find(3))
print(*a.preOrder())  # With * we splash every yielded value as argument to print().
```